# Install openblas via apt-get `sudo apt-get install openblas-dev`

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, openblas

Is it possible to install openblas via apt-get like `sudo apt-get install openblas-dev`?

Seems on ubuntu 14.04 it can't find it.

```
sudo apt-get install openblas-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openblas-dev
```

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
apt-cache search openblas

libblas-test - Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines 3, testing programs
libopenblas-base - Optimized BLAS (linear algebra) library based on GotoBLAS2
libopenblas-dev - Optimized BLAS (linear algebra) library based on GotoBLAS2
```

So `sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev` solved the problem.

Comment: This should be the top search result for "OpenBlas apt Ubuntu"!

Comment: How to install on a remote server where I don't have root permission?