# Can not compile torch on x ubuntu 15.10

Tags: torch

This is the error I get.

```
./Makefile.tail:40: recipe for target 'libs' failed
make[1]: *** [libs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/OpenBLAS/kernel'
Makefile:133: recipe for target 'libs' failed
make: *** [libs] Error 1
Error. OpenBLAS could not be compiled
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem with
`sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev`
as suggested in 
[Install openblas via apt-get `sudo apt-get install openblas-dev`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483054/install-openblas-via-apt-get-sudo-apt-get-install-openblas-dev)