# Unable to install Scipy with MKL using Meson

Tags: pip, scipy, blas, intel-mkl, meson-build

I am attempting to install scipy 1.9.1 with the MKL implementation of BLAS, using pip as my package manager.  For numpy, I can do this with: `pip install numpy --no-binary numpy`. Doing this with Scipy (`pip install scipy--no-binary scipy`) fails with the error:

> Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
>
> ../../scipy/meson.build:130:0: ERROR: Dependency "OpenBLAS" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake

I cannot figure out how to configure scipy/meson to use a specific version of BLAS, it always looks for OpenBLAS.  Older versions of scipy could accomplish this in a variety of ways using environment variables or site.cfg settings, but the new meson build system [specifically no long supports this](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/dev/contributor/building.html#reference-for-build-options).

Any suggestions how I can build scipy from the source using a specific BLAS library (ideally with pip)?

Comment: This github issue might be related: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/16308

Comment: I am trying to run the installation on Cygwin and it seems the issue is that openblas-devel just doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

From looking at partial error provide, it seems either libopenblas development package or pkg-config command is missing. Below is the command to install them(for ubuntu or debian based system)

`apt install libopenblas-dev  pkg-config libopenblas64-dev`

Depending on what are the other packages installed on system you may need to install below packages.

`apt install patchelf python3-pythran cython3 gfortran`

Answer (score 0):

For those arriving here via search engine: If your error looks like this:

```
ERROR: Dependency lookup for OpenBLAS with method 'pkgconfig' failed: Pkg-config binary for machine 1 not found. Giving up
```

you can fix this with a manual install of pkgconfig using:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

After I did this, scipy==1.10.0 compiled like a charm :) [[after creating an additional swap-file, I then ran out of RAM]]

Additional Information:

- System Configuration: Odroid HC1 (32-Bit ARMv7) on Ubuntu 22.04
- Issue appeared following the taiga project management software manual installation guide (https://docs.taiga.io/setup-production.html#setup-prod-from-source-code)
- At step: pip install -r requirements.txt
- Don't mind if it takes a bit longer: The low power architecture is not that fast in compiling
- The same architecture is the issue why you need to compile every package incoming via pip and therefore need the compilation tools, downloaded by pkg-config

Hope this will help :)

PC

*How I found out:*

- *I found a hint on stackoverflow: [Install openblas via apt-get `sudo apt-get install openblas-dev`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483054/install-openblas-via-apt-get-sudo-apt-get-install-openblas-dev)*
- *Unfortunately the manual install of OpenBlas did not work for me*
- *But I tried to use the search function for pkg-config: apt-cache search pkg*
- *Then I tried installing and it worked :)*