# Does openblas-devel exist for Cygwin?

Tags: python, pip, scipy, cygwin, openblas

I am trying unsuccessfully to install `scipy` on Cygwin.

I tried running:

```
pip install scipy
```

and it complains that "openblas-devel"  doesn't exist. The Cygwin installer/package manager  doesn't seem to know about any package that is named such or similarly.

I can run "cygcheck" to see that I have the openblas that is there for Cygwin:

```
$ cygcheck -l liblapack0
/etc/profile.d/lapack0.csh
/etc/profile.d/lapack0.sh
/usr/lib/lapack/cygblas-0.dll
/usr/lib/lapack/cyglapack-0.dll
```

and

```
$ cygcheck -l libopenblas
/usr/bin/cygblas-0.dll
```

I found threads with [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628794/unable-to-install-scipy-with-mkl-using-meson) issues and I found a [hint](https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin/2020-April/244676.html) to this issue on a mailing list by the maintainer of the package [openblas for cygwin](https://cygwin.com/cygwin/packages/summary/openblas-src.html) as it seems.

This makes me believe that there is maybe a way to use what I already have installed in a different way in order to get the installation done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not exist.
The nearest equivalent is `liblapack-devel`

Comment: is there a way to replace openblas-devel in the installation of scipy in cygwin with liblapack-devel?

Comment: @JannisErhard per the [mailing list](https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin/2020-April/244676.html) and the [scipy docs](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/blas_lapack.html), if you have liblapack-devel and libopenblas installed then you can run `pip install scipy -Csetup-args=-Dblas=blas -Csetup-args=-Dlapack=lapack`  and scipy will link to openblas at runtime. By doing so I got it to compile at least, still waiting to see if it completes and how the performance is. If you have an older version of pip you'll need to follow the `python -m build...` version at the second link there.

Comment: Yes, it seems to have worked. Make sure you install a recent version of numpy first, or let that process install a version scipy can use for you. The one in cygwin is too old.